# Center 2 button without position:absolute

Tags: html, css

Before you will think that it's a duplicate, it's not. I have searched exactly for this question and I didn't found anything.

Okay, back to the point. So I have 2 buttons. I want to center these buttons. I had found a solution, but there's a `position: absolute;` in. I don't want to use that. The other solution was:

```
.class {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

This wasn't working too. I changed `block` to `inline-block`, but that wasn't working also.

HTML:

```
<button class="inloggen">Inloggen</button>
<button class="werken">Werken</button>
```

So, is there a solution to center 2 button's?

Comment: can you please provide html and css

Comment: Edited @joshAdams

Comment: please see my solution added now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.centerButton {
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<div class="centerButton">
  <button class="inloggen">Inloggen</button>
  <button class="werken">Werken</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `text-align:center` to the parent **block** div to align the **inline** child elements or inline content like **text** to center.

```css
.main {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <button>One</button>
  <button>Two</button>
</div>
```